# Angular Compnent - Type '(data: any) => any' is missing the following properties from type

Tags: angular, laravel

I have Angular Frontend and Laravel Endpoint. In my Angular, I have model, service. While trying to run the code I got this error.

> (property) PremiumSmsProductListComponent.products: Cloudsubscriptions[]
>   Type '(data: any) => any' is missing the following properties from type 'Cloudsubscriptions[]': data, success, pop, push, and 27 more.ts(2740)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CloudsubscriptionsService } from '../../../services/cloudsubscriptions.service';
import Cloudsubscriptions from '../../../models/cloudsubscriptions';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-premium-sms-product-list',
  templateUrl: './premium-sms-product-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./premium-sms-product-list.component.scss']
})
 export class PremiumSmsProductListComponent implements OnInit {

  isLoadingResults = true;    

  products: Cloudsubscriptions[];
  constructor(private bs: CloudsubscriptionsService) { }
  deleteCloudsubscription(id) {
this.bs.deleteCloudsubscription(id).subscribe(res => {
  console.log('Deleted');
});
  }

  ngOnInit() {

this.bs
.getCloudsubscription()
.subscribe((data: Cloudsubscriptions[]) => {
  console.log(data.data);
  if(data.success==true)
  {
    this.products = data.data;
  }

  });
```

models:   cloudsubscriptions.ts

```
export default class Cloudsubscriptions {
 public msisdn: string;
 public is_subscribe: number;
 public package_id: number;
 public transaction_id: string;
 public platform_transaction_id: number;
 public status: string;
 public amount: string;
 public transaction_type: string;
 public channel: string;
 public service_name: string;
}
```

So, I goth this error

[image: subscription]

[image]

How do I resolve it

Comment: Can you share your Cloudsubscriptions interface?

Comment: I have updated it

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the subscription returns an array of `Cloudsubscriptions`.

If this is true, this should work

`this.products = data;`

Your code seems to assume that `data` is an object with the following structure.

```
data = {
   data : CloudSubscriptions[]
   success: Boolean
}
```

Instead of `console.log(data.data);` try `console.log(data)` to see what the subscription is actually returning.

Comment: Now I have another error:     ERROR in src/app/components/sms/premium-sms-product-list/premium-sms-product-list.component.ts(30,15): error TS2339: Property 'success' does not exist on type 'Cloudsubscriptions[]'.